# Comment dit-on « hum hum, ça va » ?

Tags: prononciation

J'ai lu la phrase « hum hum, ça va » (comme réponse à « Comment vous trouvez ma cuisine ? ») dans mon livre de français. Comment on la dit ?

Sur wikitionnaire, « [hum](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hum) » se prononce [œm] ou [ɔm] (comme « homme »). Mais on dit quand même [ɔm ɔm] dans la vraie vie ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il me semble qu'il y a trois prononciations possibles:

- une sorte de coup de glotte nasalisé, avec ou sans ouvrir la bouche, que je ne vois pas comment écrire en alphabet phonétique. C'est le son le plus courant, et c'est celui qui me vient à l'esprit dans votre exemple « hum hum, ça va ».
- un raclement de gorge qui se termine en fermant les lèvres, qui est précisément ce que cherche à transcrire l'écriture « hum hum ». Il peut être utilisé pour exprimer l'agacement ou le mécontentement, ou pour chercher à attirer l'attention.
- la prononciation /œm œm/ me paraît influencée par la graphie. C'est souvent celle qui est utilisée quand on lit à voix haute un texte avec « hum hum », mais peut-être pas la plus naturelle dans la vie courante.

Quand à la prononciation /ɔm ɔm/ (« homme homme »), je ne l'ai jamais entendue et elle me paraît bizarre, mais elle peut correspondre à des variantes régionales.

Comment: Dans le premier cas, on le dit avec l'intonation en baisse (?) sur le premier « hum », et l'intonation montante sur le second « hum », comme en anglais quand on veut exprimer un « oui » plus léger ?

Comment: Je dirais qu'il est fréquent que le premier soit émis avec une intonation plus aiguë que le deuxième, ou que l'intonation monte sur le premier et descende sur le deuxième, mais ce n'est pas une règle générale.

Answer (score 2):

Cela dépend également du contexte de la phrase.

Ici j'ai l'impression que c'est la réponse à la question "Comment vas-tu ?"

Dans ce cas-là le **hum hum** correspond à un **oui oui** mais marmonné.

Donc phonétiquement il se prononcerait [m m] **mm mm**

Mais **hum hum** cela peut également être perçu comme un raclement de gorge, dans ce cas-là, ça se prononcerait [œm œm].

Answer (score 0):

Ceci est un [community wiki](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki). Chacun pouvant ainsi ajouter sa façon de prononcer.

Il est fort possible que tu aies beaucoup de réponses pour cette question car cela peut dépendre des régions et variétés de français.

- Moi je dis /œm/ mais j'entends fréquememnt /ɔm/. Pas d'accent particulier, ou alors mélange d'accent méridional et circum-parisien.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/um-hum

> um-hum interjection
>
> \ a sound made with the organs of speech in position for m, a voiced
> beginning which usually has the heaviest stress, and a voiced ending
> separated by an h-like period of voicelessness \
>
> Definition of um-hum —used to express affirmation, agreement,
> comprehension, or interest

Comment: So what's you opinion on that? How does it link to the french interjection? Quote-only answers are not suited for this site.